# NSMutableString appendString in first position

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I have a NSMutableString variable that i append from aString, like this:

```
NSString  *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"MyCode\":%@,\"TotalAmount\":%@,\"PaymentType\":\"%@\",\"BankName\":\"%@\",\"BankAccountNo\":\"%@\",\"Amount\":\"%@\",\"FileName\":\"%@\"}",aCode,total,type,labelBank.txt,labelAcc.txt,aTrasfer,imageName];

[teststring appendString:asstring2];
[teststring appendString:@","];
```

in this code i sucess to append the string in order they append. But know i want to append a new string in the first position, just like in array object at index 0.Can NSMutableString do this?

Hope my question is clear..thanks

Comment: Please look at the reference docs before asking a question like this. One minute looking at the NSMutableSting docs would have showed the proper methods for this.

Comment: @rmaddy I am surprised how many people are like "hey wouldn't it be cool if X method existed" only to find them in the documentation. Aren't you supposed to look there first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it, with an index. Same way as you do with an array.

```
- (void)insertString:(NSString *)aString atIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex
```

Your code:

```
[testString appendString:aString];
[testString insertString:@"," atIndex:0]; /* prepend the comma
```

Check out the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)